# Python Pandas Join with Index value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, concatenation

i want to join 2 DataFrames for example like:
DataFrame1:

```
A 1
B 2
C 3
D 4
```

DataFrame2:

```
A 1
A 3
B 4
B 3
B 7
C 4
D 6
D 8
```

The result should look like:

```
A 1 1    
    3    
B 2 4    
    3    
    7    
C 3 4
D 4 6    
    8
```

I tried join merge and concat, but nothing works can you help me please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is like this:

```
df_out = pd.concat([df1,df2])

df_out.set_index([0,df_out.groupby([0]).cumcount()])[1].unstack()
```

Output:

```
     0    1    2    3
0                    
A  1.0  1.0  3.0  NaN
B  2.0  4.0  3.0  7.0
C  3.0  4.0  NaN  NaN
D  4.0  6.0  8.0  NaN
```

### Edit Update to match expected output:

```
df_out = pd.concat([df1,df2])

df_out = df_out.set_index([0,df_out.groupby([0]).cumcount()])[1]

df_out.sort_index()
```

Output:

```
A  0    1
   1    1
   2    3
B  0    2
   1    4
   2    3
   3    7
C  0    3
   1    4
D  0    4
   1    6
   2    8
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

### Edit Update a litte more...

```
df_out = pd.concat([df1,df2])

df_out = df_out.set_index([0,df_out.groupby([0]).cumcount()])[1]

df_out = df_out.sort_index().to_frame()

df_out = df_out.reset_index().drop('level_1', axis=1)

df_out[0] = df_out[0].mask(df_out[0].duplicated()).fillna('')

print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
    0  1
0   A  1
1      1
2      3
3   B  2
4      4
5      3
6      7
7   C  3
8      4
9   D  4
10     6
11     8
```

Comment: @Beginner2018 is that it?

Comment: It is best if you edited your question.  Lead each line of your expected output with four spaces.

Comment: In pandas, each line must have a index label, hence the 0,1,2 01,2,3... etc line in my output.

Comment: Bosten really thanks :D it worked now with breaklines. And BIG thanks also for the code

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = [['A', 1],
         ['B', 2],
         ['C', 3],
         ['D', 4]]

data2 = [['A', 1],
         ['A', 3],
         ['B', 4],
         ['B', 3],
         ['B', 7],
         ['C', 4],
         ['D', 6],
         ['D', 8]]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1, columns=['c1', 'c2'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2, columns=['c1', 'c2'])
result = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('c1')['c2'].apply(list)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
c1
A       [1, 1, 3]
B    [2, 4, 3, 7]
C          [3, 4]
D       [4, 6, 8]
Name: c2, dtype: object
```

Or without columns:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2)
result = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby(0)[1].apply(list)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
0
A       [1, 1, 3]
B    [2, 4, 3, 7]
C          [3, 4]
D       [4, 6, 8]
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh .apply(list) applies the function list to the groups of the groupby.

Comment: @Beginner could you be more specific?